# Override dynamic route if exact match is found

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm pretty new to using v4 of React Router, and am currently struggling with the following scenario

```
<Route exact path="/campaign/new" component={CampaignEditor}/>
<Route exact path="/campaign/:id" component={Campaign}/>
```

I want the exact match `/campaign/new` to go render `CampaignEditor`. In all other cases, I want to render `Campaign` with the dynamic id as a parameter.

I can of course render the editor in the campaign component if the parameter equals "new", but is there a way to do it with the router?

Comment: That route already exists at `/campaign/:id/edit` and works great. There shouldn't really be a problem for both of them to point to `CampaignEditor` as far as I know. The above would be to create a new campaign, which doesn't have an id yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make use of [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) and you can render the routes like

```
<Router>
     <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/campaign/new" component={CampaignEditor}/>
          <Route path="/campaign/:id" component={Campaign}/>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```